# Filter RDDs using clojure and flambo

Tags: clojure, apache-spark

I have an RDD with index of the form: `(:rdd xctx)`

```
[[["1" "32" "44" "55" "14"] 0] [["21" "23" "24" "25" "24"] 1] [["41" "53" "54" "5" "24"] 2] [["11" "35" "34" "15" "64"] 3]]
```

and I want to filter out the RDDs that have their indexes in a vector for example:

```
:row-list s[1 3]
```

I tried this but somehow I'm getting an error:

```
(defn remove-index-rows
 "Function to catch the row(s) with the specific Row Number(s) in rows-list
  input = { :rows-list [ val(s)]}"
  [row input]
  (let [{:keys [ rows-list ]} input
    row-and-index (f/collect (f/filter #(= row (get % 0)) (:rdd xctx)))]
    (when-not (some #(= (get row-and-index 1) %) rows-list) row)))
```

Desired output is:

```
 [ [["1" "32" "44" "55" "14"] 0] [["41" "53" "54" "5" "24"] 2] ]
```

Thanks for helping out

Comment: @zero323 can you please help me out with the above question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starers I would replace rows-list with set. Lets define it as follows

```lisp
(set row-list)
```

After that you can simply filter like this:

```lisp
(f/filter
 (:rdd xctx)
 (f/fn [row] (let [[v i] row] (not (contains? row-set i)))))
```